# Url rewriting doing a redirect instead of a source mapping

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I installed a wordpress on a server and put it under the folder apps/wordpress/.

What I want to do is the make the wordpress available using te url http://mydomain.com/blog instead of the url http://mydomain.com/apps/wordpress

In order to do that I wrote a .htaccess file that I put at the root of my server. Here is the file :

```
RewriteEngine    on
RewriteBase      /
RewriteRule      ^blog$    blog/  [PT]
RewriteRule      ^blog     /app/wordpress  [PT]
```

The problem is that instead of giving me the content of apps/wordpress, the browser receive a 301 and then redirect to apps/wordress. What I want to do is to hide the apps/wordpress url behind /blog not doing a redirect.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: The non-technical way would be to change the folder apps/wordpress to blog/, but I'm assuming you don't want to do that for some reason?

Comment: Do you know what the [`P` and `T` flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html) do? Are you sure it isn't the WordPress configuration doing the redirect?

Comment: I even try this locally without wordpress or anything else. Just the apps/wordpress architecture
I also try a lot of [L] [L,R] [R] flag combinaison an devery time it's a redirect which is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I don't know why, but this is working:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog/
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /apps/wordpress/$1
```

Doesn't matter, it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive instead, which would be:

```
   Alias /blog   /<path to htdocs>/app/wordpress
```